# How to find out touching lines?

Tags: python, shapely

I work with python library [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely)

I have two `Polygons` and I try to extract lines with mutual touching. (to find all lines where polygons touch each other) as in the picture:

[image: example]

I have tried:

```
(l1).intersects(l2) 
(l1).intersects(l2).exterior
(l1.exterior).intersects(l2.exterior)
```

But it didn't help. How I can do that?

Comment: Have you tried `l1.intersects(l2)`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work

Comment: It may be that the lines aren't geometrically touching, even if they appear closely located next to each other.

Comment: Do you have the WKT of specific geometries in this question?

Comment: "intersects" returns a boolean describing whether or not the shapes touch. You're looking for "intersection", which returns the actual result of the intersect operation. Try "l1.intersection(l2)".